# Two functions is the same in the limit

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Can anyone explain me why
$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)}=1$ when $x_n \to 1$ for $n\to \infty$ with $f(x_n)=-\log(1-(\beta/x_n)^\alpha)$, $g(x_n)=\log(\beta+x_n)^\alpha$ ?

I have tried to write out $f(x_n)$ using some logarithm-rules but cant obtain $g(x_n)$ from that (with obtain i mean it in a limiting sense)

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $\alpha,\beta$?

Comment: could you precise the parenthesising for $g$ ?

Comment: Sorry, alpha and beta is positive.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no restrictions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then this is false by taking $\alpha=\beta=1$, you have that, $\lim \frac{f(x_n)}{g(x_n)}=\infty$ when $x_n$ goes to $1$.

Comment: You are totally right. It is because I am working with a paper about large deviation regarding my thesis, where a lot of the results from the paper is without any explanations, so when I ask the question here I have tried to done it “simple” without all the assumptions behind.